# Can't understand step in posterior mean derivation

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I was studying the [Conjugate Priors](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture4.pdf) section of Berkeley's *Stat260: Bayesian Modeling and Inference* where, when looking at Poisson Gamma conjugacy, the following is given (page 3)

> The posterior distribution has density
>   $$
> P(\theta|x, \alpha)\propto \theta^{\sum_{j} x_{j} + \alpha_{1} - 1}e^{-(\alpha_{2}+n)\theta}
> $$
>   so that
>   $$
> E[\theta|x, \alpha] = \color{#C00}{\frac{\sum_{j}x_{j}+\alpha_{1}}{n+\alpha_{2}} = \kappa\frac{\alpha_{1}}{\alpha_{2}} + (1-\kappa)\frac{\sum_{j}x_{j}}{n}}
> $$
>   where $\kappa = \alpha_{1}/(\alpha_{2}+n)$.

Embarrassingly, I can't understand the equality I emphasized in red - despite my efforts expanding the equation with the value of $\kappa$ to $$\frac{\alpha^{2}}{\beta(\beta+n)} + \frac{\sum_{j}x_{j}}{n}-\frac{\alpha\sum_{j}x_{j}}{n(\beta+n)}$$

I cannot see how the equality holds. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your quoted definition of $\kappa$. If you redefine it to be $\kappa\equiv\beta/(\beta+n)$, then everything makes sense:

$$\frac{\sum_{i}x_{i}+\alpha}{n+\beta}=\frac{\sum_{i}x_{i}}{n+\beta}+\frac{\alpha}{n+\beta} = \frac{n}{n+\beta}\cdot\frac{\sum_{i}x_{i}}{n} + \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\frac{\beta}{n+\beta}$$
$$= (1-\kappa)\cdot\frac{\sum_{i}x_{i}}{n} + \kappa\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$

Comment: Yes, I think you're right - it must be a typo. Thank you!